# Android Studio cannot detect project structure of a flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Initially, I was looking why I could not open the emulator window, then I found out that the main reason for that was that android studio cannot detect flutter project structure automatically, due to the missing ".iml" files and ".idea" folder, due to which it does not know the existence of two modules i.e my_project and my_project_android.
Can anyone help me? Why is this happening?

Note:- Android studio can detect flutter project structure just fine if I create a project from my computer only, but since I am importing a project from GitHub, it cannot detect the appropriate project structure.

Below is how my modules section in the project structure looks, everything section is completely empty here.

[image: file > project structure > modu]

Edit 1:-
Following are the picks on trying to import project inside modules
[image]

[image]

Edit 2:-
This is from where I import project directly from android studio using "Get from Version Control" than,
[image]

After this, I just click on clone and no more settings are asked(or required).

Comment: Goto File-->Project Structure-->Modules-->on right side there will be `Add Content Root` and select you downloaded project and also check if dart is enabled for the project,if you are not sure how to check,, Goto File-->Settings-->Lanugae and Frameworks select Dart and enable the project  and run flutter clean and pub get @Vishnu

Comment: @Assassin I have added a screenshot of the modules section in my project structure as u can see there is no ```Add Content Root``` option here.

Comment: This because you haven't set the project right,click on the `+` button and select create or import module but now stick with create module and select your flutter downloaded path it will appear automatically if not select the flutter sdk folder and select the downloaded project folder and press ok then run flutter clean and pub run@Vishnu

Comment: @Assassin I cannot import flutter module, it is saying "the selected directory is not a flutter module" and on trying to import gradle or eclipse project, on selecting my directory, next option is still greyed out and nothing happens

Comment: can you show me pics@Vishnu

Comment: @Assassin added screenshots

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem,i have different version android studio like upto date version i have no problem importing projects and how did you open the downloaded project can share that screenshot how you do it on the downloaded project @Vishnu

Comment: Added screenshot from where I add the project

Comment: Why don't you download the project from github and extract or clone with command line then try open File-->open,in most cases there will be options  shows to pub upgrade or enable dart sdk @Vishnu

Comment: @Assassin Same thing happens, while pub upgrade and "enable dart support" options do come, after the above steps I mentioned too, but those don't help in detecting or creating the project structure, these project structure images are after doing all those only, I can run the project, but still project structure is not detected correctly as we can also see in above screenshots.

Comment: Try to update android studio an try again@Vishnu

Comment: @Assassin It is saying "I already have the latest version of Android Studio and Plugins installed.", Android Studio v4.2.1

Comment: The settings windows is kind of different@Vishnu

Comment: @Assassin yup I think that is because it changes according to your current project structure, if it recognizes your project structure then it shows different settings, and if not then different, or more like it shows available options according to what it recognizes of your project, as in other projects settings looks similar as u mentioned.

Comment: like i mentioned above,the same process i have done it and it works i am not sure what in your case @Vishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the project I was getting from VCS was flawed, it had gradle files in the flutter root folder and some more problems, eventually, I created a new flutter project after that I copied dart and other files and also updated some android files, and it worked.